# How to get the screen bit depth of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In `NSScreen` Class Reference of Mac OS there is a "depth" method of `NSSCreen` which can get the bit depth of the screen, but that doesn't exsit in UIScreen class of iOS.Does any one know how can detect the bit depth of the screen on iPhone?
[`NSScreen` Class Reference of Mac OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Donn't all iOS devices have a depth of 32?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All current Mac OS X and iOS devices always run in 32-bit color.

It used to be the case that Mac OS X supported 8- and 16-bit color modes, but that is no longer the case. iOS has always run in 32-bit color, so there is no need for a method to query the color depth.

Comment: What i don't understand is why `NSScreen` `depth` returns `24` and not `32` for me. Shouldn't it be 32 bit?

Comment: @Danilo 24-bit and 32-bit color are nearly synonymous. They both mean 8 bits for each R/G/B component; the extra 8 bits in 32-bit color may be used for an alpha channel, or left unused as padding.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit color refers to 8 bits each for R, G, and B, and 8 bits for alpha transparency. Hence the screen depth would seem to relate to the RGB values.